# Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 VMWare hangs on setting up the partioner

Tags: 18.04, windows, vmware

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I have tried reinstalling, no help.  Windows 10 desktop, AMD Ryzen 5 1600/16 Gig/1060 Nvidia/Gigabyte AB350/one static drive, one HDD.  New windows 10 Pro installation/machine.

When I try to install on VMWare via the ISO it hangs at "setting up the partitioner" and never goes any further, white circle on orange background.

Really frustrating, cannot access terminal, cannot boot